# Bash Equivalency Struggles

Tags: command-line, bash, pulseaudio, equivs

Where am I going wrong in this Bash?

```
declare current_state=`pacmd list-sources | sed -n 19p`
declare my_target='used by: 0'
echo $current_state = $my_target
if [ '$current_state' = '$my_target' ] ; then
    echo true
    pacmd set-default-sink "alsa_output.pci-0000_0c_00.4.analog-stereo"
    echo true
else
    echo false
    pacmd set-default-sink "alsa_output.pci-0000_0a_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra2"
    echo false
fi
```

It is always outputting the else (false) option to terminal:

```
used by: 0 = used by: 0
false
false
```

I have tried `if [[ '$current_state' = '$my_target' ]]` , `if [[ '$current_state' == '$my_target' ]]`, `if [ '$current_state' == '$my_target' ]`, `if [ '$current_state' == 'used by 0:' ]`, `if [ '$current_state' = 'used by 0:' ]`, etc. It's always coming back as false.

For context, I was trying to use scripts from [How to switch sound output with key shortcut](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156895/how-to-switch-sound-output-with-key-shortcut#) but none of those work because my output indeces are 2, 3, and 30. Because that makes sense. Anyway, I found by running the pacmd list-sources while varying the manually selected outputs out of Sound Settings differences in a few lines. (Line 6 was what I initially tried, and it would report the status of one of index 2 (the first one, yes, the first) as `state: IDLE`, `state: RUNNING`, or `state: SUSPENDED`.) I managed to make the bash script work *once* to change from my headphones to my monitor, and then no more. So I tried changing where I look to this line 19 output which tells me if it's in use (I think) with either `used by: 1` when active or `used by: 0` when inactive to just toggle. But nope, no luck.

So then I get into the basic troubleshooting to make sure my if/else is evaluating correctly, and it's not. I don't know what I'm supposed to do here. Did I screw something up with declare?? I don't know.

Comment: `"$current_state" = "$my_target"`  ... Use double quotes `"` around variables .... Single quotes prevent their expansion.

Comment: ... [www.shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/)

Comment: @Raffa no luck in doing that. Just made that single change from the code originally posted, and it's still evaluating as false.

Comment: @steeldriver using that site I can get code that says there are **No issues detected!** with this code. And it still doesn't work.
```
#!/bin/bash

current_state=$(pacmd list-sources | sed -n 19p)
my_target="used by: 0"
echo "$current_state" = "$my_target"
if [ "$current_state" = "$my_target" ] ; then
 echo true
 pacmd set-default-sink "alsa_output.pci-0000_0c_00.4.analog-stereo"
 echo true
else
 echo false
 pacmd set-default-sink "alsa_output.pci-0000_0a_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra2"
 echo false
fi
```

Comment: `pacmd list-sources` usually results in lines with leading spaces/tabs ... That might result in the two strings you are comparing to be not equal ... Spaces count.

Comment: @Raffa that helped. The problem is I used ` = ` instead of `=`. By removing the surrounding spaces on the equivalence operator, it worked. At least to evaluate as true. I still have work to do on my troubleshooting, as it isn't doing a toggle. I'll have to explore a persistent variable as a toggle I think as my answer, rather than reading an output.

Comment: You can use `=~` for partial match e.g. try `[ "   abc: 1" = "abc: 1" ] && echo "full match" || [[ "    abc: 1" =~ "abc: 1" ]] && echo "partial match"` ... notice the order of string and sub-string around `=~` and the use of `[[ ... ]]`

Comment: You need the spaces around = i.e. `"abc" = "abc"` or otherwise it will evaluate true always e.g. `"abc"="abcd"` will evaluate true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pacmd list-sources` usually results in lines with leading spaces/tabs ... That might result in the two strings you are comparing to be not equal ... Spaces count.

You can use `=~` for partial match e.g. try `[ "   abc: 1" = "abc: 1" ] && echo "full match" || [[ "    abc: 1" =~ "abc: 1" ]] && echo "partial match"` ... notice the order of string and sub-string around `=~` and the use of `[[ ... ]]`

So modifying your code:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

current_state=$(pacmd list-sources | sed -n 19p)
my_target="used by: 0"
echo "$current_state" = "$my_target"
if [[ "$current_state" =~ "$my_target" ]] ; then
    echo true
    pacmd set-default-sink "alsa_output.pci-0000_0c_00.4.analog-stereo"
    echo true
else
    echo false
    pacmd set-default-sink "alsa_output.pci-0000_0a_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra2"
    echo false
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting my mistake. I'd have been banging my head on that for a few hours when I always got a true evaluation. And thanks for teaching that [[ ]] is necessary for =~; I tried to use the regex match operator and got an error with [ ].

This seems to work other than now after waking my computer up from sleep the output devices have been renamed and reindexed (2, 3, and now 47.)