# My external USB sound card is not working

Tags: sound, external-soundcard

I am a new user of Ubuntu. I’ve been using my USB sound card for a few months. I used Windows before and it worked on Windows. But it’s not working on my Ubuntu. It can't output any sound.

Answer (score 1):

On my other laptop, internal sound card died, so I also use USB sound card ( [Daffodil US01](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002FI7GWK) ).

On the laptop I use right now, it's Ubuntu. In System Settings -> Sound you should see your usb sound card listed as headphones. Look at screen shot bellow:

[image]

If you highlight the Headphones option, you should receive sound through the usb card.

Now, you can do this every time, or you can select your USB card as default. Now there is small problem. On that laptop where I must use USB card I have Fedora, not Ubuntu, so I don't remember what steps I used, and if those steps can be used. But [this post here](https://askubuntu.com/a/435197/295286)  explains it exactly for Ubuntu.

Good Luck ! Let me now if this helps

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem when I reinstalled 22.04 after a crash. The USB audio was showing in the sound settings, but testing produced no output.

I went to the terminal and entered alsamixer. I then pressed F6 to select the sound card and chose my USB device. The gain was 00, I increased it to 50. That worked.