# Behringer UMC204HD not working on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: audio-recording

I have a Behringer UMC204HD audio interface. Audio comes out from the computer, but there is no input from the interface.

anyone can help me?

Comment: So you're saying you can't record?

Comment: Yes exactly. I can hear the Ubuntu sounds, youtube and everything normall, using the Interface Output, but I cannot record anything

Comment: Has it worked in Windows?  Does it show up in the sound device manager?

Comment: Yes, it works flawlessly, just noticed something. When I log into Ubuntu, it puts the microphone on Mute. And this stays like that, until I log into windows and un-mute the mic.

Comment: Have you tried unmuting from Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes. Still nothing

Comment: Once you unmute in Windows, does it stay unmuted in Ubuntu?

Comment: no, If I unmute in Windows, it works flawlessly on Windows, but at the moment i go into Ubuntu, it mutes it, even un-muting it doesn't do anything. When I log onto Windows once again, it shows the device Muted, and after un-muting it, it works again.

Comment: Hmm.  Sounds like a driver issue.

Comment: what can I do to fix that?

Comment: Not sure.  Maybe see this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/590623/behringer-asio-audio-card-in-ubuntu

Comment: Also try googling around.

Comment: I've already googled, and found nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your sound card is not compatible with Ubuntu.  You may be better off finding a different model, or using it only with Windows.

You can try to adapt other drivers for it, but ultimately this is beyond most users.  Perhaps you can contact the company and ask if they have Ubuntu drivers, or plan on coming out with any.

If you end up buying a different model, feel free to ship me your old one

Answer (score 0):

See https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=YP1sVctgvG0
The trick is that all inputs must be set as captured

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.