# How to configure task-specific default sound card selection?

Tags: 20.04, sound, default-programs

Every time I log on, my BT600 headset is selected as the default sound card. However, I want it to be selected only for the task I need it for, i.e. communication via Skype & colleagues. Otherwise I'd like the NVidia to make the default. Annoyingly, I have to manually reset this after each login and before each Skype etc. call.

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [SB             ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI SB
                      HDA ATI SB at 0xfe700000 irq 16
 1 [BT600          ]: USB-Audio - Poly BT600
                      Plantronics Poly BT600 at usb-0000:00:13.0-1, full speed
 2 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xfe080000 irq 68
 3 [U0x46d0x825    ]: USB-Audio - USB Device 0x46d:0x825
                      USB Device 0x46d:0x825 at usb-0000:04:00.0-2, high speed
```

According to [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1203264/897783) I made following entries,

```
$ sudo cat /etc/asound.conf
defaults.pcm.card 2
defaults.ctl.card 2
```

but it won't work, I can't notice any changes in the setting. Also if it worked, I doubt that this setting selects the headset for communication and sets it back to line out after hanging up.